# Tehillim while waiting for medical test results

Tags: minhag, medicine, tehilim-psalms

When one is waiting for a medical test result, which tehillim is it customary to recite?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a tefillat shav, since the condition already exists and you can't change something once it's already been decreed?

Comment: the test is to determine IF condition exists

Comment: @Rena just because you don't know doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I don't understand your logic. You're not saying Tefilot you're just reciting verses from Tehilim.

Comment: rena, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around and see other content here of interest to you, perhaps including our 55 other questions about [tag:tehilim-psalms]. If this question is immediately relevant to you or yours, I join you in hoping God grants a favorable result.

Comment: @DoubleAA, IIRC we don't pray for good silo contents once we open the silo doors: but until then we do, even a minute before, even though the grain is already good- or bad-quality. This is because until a status is seen by human eyes it can still be changed by God without our knowledge, and he may well do so. That's my understanding, anyway: I'm glad to be corrected if I'm wrong.

Comment: @HachamGabriel - But most Psalms are prayers.

Comment: @AdamMosheh ya but there is no way it can be a Tefilat Shav because it's Pesukim as well.

Comment: @HachamGabriel - *Een hachee nammee*, and that would be the other *tzad*.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, related: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%2012%20Bleicher.pdf

Comment: @HachamGabriel^^^

Answer (score 3):

The Minhag at the Yeshivos where I learned as a Bochur was to recite numbers 121, 130 and 142 followed by the pesukim of "temanya Apei" (eight facets, ie eight pesukim for each letter) of tehilla #119 with the letters corresponding to the name and mothers name.
One important thing to bear in mind is that as long as a definite diagnosis hasn't been confirmed the collaborative efforts and zechuyos of the Tehillim said along with a genuine acceptance to take on an extra detail in the service of Hashem (eg to read the bracha "Asher Yotzar" with concentration from a printed text) has a much stronger change of success of overturning the gezeira than once the diagnosis is confirmed a miracle is needed.

Comment: Y Revah, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for documenting this minhag here! I hope you'll look around and find other content here that interests you, perhaps including our 613 (!) other questions about [tag:minhag]. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 2):

One may not think as he recites Tehillim that they are a cure. (see [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1222)).

Tehillim are essentially praise of Hashem which can be followed by a prayer for healing. see [here](http://www.mesora.org/Tehillim5770b.html).

Therefore I suggest that you say the Tehillim which arouse you most to the praise of Hashem.